# Save EditText and TextView data and display it in another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, textview

I'm developing an app which adds two numbers. The user provides the numbers via EditText and the result is displayed via TextView. What I want to do is to save the values of the numbers entered by the user and the result via button (to see them whenever the user wants) and display them in the layout of another activity (whithout EditText's). Remark that the user would be able to see the results saved whenever he/she wants.

Hope you can help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Read [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and then if you can't figure it out, come back here with some code of what you tried and you'll get better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple ways to achieve that :

**Method 1:**
Use static class setter and getter method:

create static class and set values from first activity and get value from second activity

**Method 2:**

Post your values through the intent

**Method 3:**

Use database to store data from one activity and get data from other activity

**Method 4:**

Use Shared preference

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm new to android development, so I have to dive more into this topic

Answer (score 0):

**From Your question what i understand**::

- Your first `editText1` has `value1`
- Your second `editText2` has `value2`
- `textView1` has the result of `value1` and `value2`

---

**Solution**:: Get the values from the `views` and use `intents` to pass the data between `activities`

---

**Code**::

***`In your current Activity, create a new Intent:`*** - **`OnCreate()`**

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("editText1",editText1.getText());
i.putExtra("editText2",editText2.getText());
i.putExtra("textView1",textView1.getText());
startActivity(i);
```

***`Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:`*** - **`OnCreate()`**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String editText1= extras.getString("editText1");
    String editText2= extras.getString("editText2");
    String textView1= extras.getString("textView1");
}
```

***Use the variables `editText1`,`editText2` and `textView1` in second activity to set the values to any views as u wish***

---

*HOPE THAT HELPS, let me know if you face any problems in debugging*

Comment: Have you read this line `Remark that the user would be able to see the results saved whenever he/she wants.`?

Answer (score 0):

make use of `SharedPreferences` like this:

```
SharedPreferences sp= getSharedPreferences("ttt", 0);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

String etValue=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId).getText().toString();

String tvValue=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextView).getText().toString();

editor.putString("etValue", etValue);

editor.putString("tvValue", tvValue);

editor.commit();

// in anywhere user wants

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ttt", 0);

String yourEditTextValue=settings.getString("etValie", "");

String yourTextViewValue=settings.getString("tvValie", "");
```

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your edit , will try better from next time